# SqlDataReader.GetSqlBinary vs SqlDataReader.GetSqlBytes?

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclient, system.data

Under the namespace `System.Data.SqlClient`, we have both [SqlDataReader.GetSqlBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlbinary.aspx) 
 and [SqlDataReader.GetSqlBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlbytes.aspx).

Both seems to give "raw data". If so, what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetSQLBytes are stored in an inside buffer for more manipulation, the Binary are just a stream that you get and use it as it is.

This two return [SqlBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.aspx) and [SqlBinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary.aspx) and by see this two types you can see the full different of them and how they store the data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.storage.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[`GetSqlBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlbinary.aspx) returns an [`SqlBinary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbinary.aspx) structure:

> Represents a variable-length stream of binary data to be stored in or retrieved from a database.

[`GetSqlBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getsqlbytes.aspx) returns an [`SqlBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlbytes.aspx) class:

> Represents a mutable reference type that wraps either a Buffer or a Stream.

So is seems that the difference is that `GetSqlBinary` gives you a lump of data as a byte array, while `GetSqlBytes` is similar but stores the data in a buffer which allows you to interact with the underlying data as a stream.